# Android button TouchListener vertical motion

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

I use it **TouchListener**

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

to make drag and drop for button.
How to change it for what motion was only in the vertical direction?

Comment: so you want to check whether it is horizontal or vertical direction? right?

Comment: I want to do so that the button does not move in the horizontal direction

Comment: here event gives x and y coordinates of the touch positions, then you have to validate the conditions like, x will decrease but y can not change like that, then only move the view.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start your drag on Action.MOVE.  Try something like the following:

```
        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            int dx = lastX - ev.getX();
            int dy = lastY - ev.getY();

            //do something here.  

            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();
        }
```

Now you can check something like if(dy>dx) startDrag to account for touch slop.  Also, you can now animate your button move to ev.getY() and ignore ev.getX().

Check out this link for a good overview of how [touch dispatch](http://im-dexter.blogspot.com/2013/01/handling-touch-events-in-viewgroup.html?showComment=1379455694571) works.

Comment: Strangely enough, it does not go into the block > if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) { }

Comment: Oh, don't return true from the ACTION_DOWN part.

Comment: In that case, I'd check: 1) Nothing else is grabbing the touch events (see the link above), 2) You are touching what you think you are touching, 3) the touch listener is set on the thing you think it is.

Comment: I TouchListener depend only on the buttons. If I put toast before "if blocks", something like that > https://codeo.me/3nj then displays different coordinates. First coordinates of button in a container(for example x=270 y=50) than button moves, on the spot where I touched turns the center of the button and than shows coordinates of button in a screen(for example x=297 y=198).